# Adding to the end of arrayList java

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

The problem im having is adding objects from a related class(a parent) to an arrayList made in the child. I have a array List made of parent objects:

```
 ArrayList<Parent>elements = new ArrayList<Parent>();//creating an array list
```

And i trying to append/add values to the end of a list using a method:

```
 public void addElement(Parent e)
 {elements.add(e);//has an error}
```

This is where the problem is, do i have to specify the position i want to add the element or does my code have another problem?

I couldn't find a duplicate but if there's one please direct me to it.Thanks

Edit - this is error:

```
1020\Asssignment 3\GUIgroup.java  [line: 14]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method add(GUIelement)
  location: variable elements of type GUIelement
```

GUIgroup is the subclass and GUIelement is the superclass.

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: A cannot find symbol error, specifically the method.add(parent)

Comment: Did you implement a class and called it: `ArrayList` ?

Comment: `method.add(parent)` ? Please share the code.

Comment: Are you sure it can't find the method, seems more likely it can't find `elements`. Are you sure `elements` is defined in the correct scope? If you share more of the code it would be helpful.

Comment: There is no ArrayList class, the parent is the name im using for the super class. The method is adding super class objects to a sublass arrayList

Comment: @D.B.  I'm still new to programming, what does correct scope mean?

Comment: Can you please share more of your code so that we can check if the variables are within scope or not? Also do share the exact error

Comment: If you're not familiar with variable scope I suggest you start with the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/). To learn about scope specifically you can read about [variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared the array list elements in parent class, there's a possibility that it is not being accessed in sub class due to some scope issues. But that doesn't look like a problem.

Your main problem is as it looks like the compiler thinks elements is not an array list but a variable of type GUIelement which does not have any add() method associated thus your error.  Just try checking why it might be taking elements as a GUIelement object.

Comment: Thanks, that seems plausible. Let me see if i can find the issue